# crashing on ios device while navigation using UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, curl, ios4, xcode4

i am using UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl on the ios 4 device,in my test app i have 2 classes where a single button in each class, in first page onclick of the button it ill navigate to 2nd page (by curling the page up) but in the 2nd page when i click backbutton its crashing but not navigating back to my first page
 following is my code used for navigation

```
ViewController *MainWin = [[QIAViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];
    MainWin.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:MainWin animated:YES];
    [MainWin release];
```

this is the crash log:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nested modal view controller while curled <QIAAdminPassCnf: 0x583e040>.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl), you will see that once you've used it you can't present any more modal views.

If you want to navigate back, I think you should do,

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

rather than creating a new view controller instance.

Comment: ya u r correct but suppose i have 3 classes, on click of a button in first page it will navigate to second(by curling up) & in the second page say i have a button  NEXT ,on click of that it should go to third class,, but here again its crashing with the same crash log

Comment: Exactly. The documentation says that you can't add any more modal views. So after you go from 1 to 2 using a curled up modal view you can't add one more.

Comment: +1 Deepak, yes thats correct even he can see the documentation as well.

Answer (score -1):

You may well have added the Action twice in Interface Builder. Go to the ViewController and to the Triggered Segues on the right and "x" do delete the extra one. LOL