# iPad Simulator Crashing, "NSInvalidArgumentException"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [crashing on ios device while navigation using UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463574/crashing-on-ios-device-while-navigation-using-uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-i)

HI I am making an app which is a test, halfway through the middle, i run, and i get a crash in my switching page code, this never happened before, suddenly it happened. weird right? This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)fail {
Fail *fail = [[Fail alloc]
              initWithNibName:@"Fail" bundle:nil];
fail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:fail animated:YES];

 }
```

Here is my console crash log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:     'Application tried to present a nested modal view controller while curled <QThree:    0x5537190>.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00f025a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01056313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x000d2bac -[UIViewController     presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 741
    3   Smart2                              0x0000730a -[QThree fail] + 135
    4   UIKit                               0x0001f4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    5   UIKit                               0x000af799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    6   UIKit                               0x000b1c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    7   UIKit                               0x000b07d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    8   UIKit                               0x00043ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    9   UIKit                               0x00024c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    10  UIKit                               0x00029f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x0113b992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee3944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00e43cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00e40f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00e40840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00e40761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0113a1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0113a289 GSEventRun + 115
    19  UIKit                               0x0002dc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  Smart2                              0x00003092 main + 83
    21  Smart2                              0x00002911 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

I have no idea what the problem is, especially why it suddenly rose up in one build, i cant remember which code i added because its actually been a while since i last built. SOO!

Comment: If you read the console log you posted, it tells you exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already presented a view modally with a page curl effect, according to the 'crash'. Unlike other modal presentations, page curl modal view controllers cannot be stacked. Therefore, this exception is being raised as this is what you are trying to do; present a modal view controller inside another modal view controller with a page curl effect.

To stop this, you are going to have to refactor your app workflow or present the first modal view controller with a different animation.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you've presented a view with style `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`.  You can't present another modal view after that, you have to dismiss the curled view first.